# Знакомство с тестами

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты

Никогда не писал модульных тестов, появилось задание с ними познакомиться и научиться использовать. Есть некая функция "сортировки" массива в консольном приложении, необходимо протестировать ее работу.

Из теории понял только то, что необходимо воспользоваться какими-то сторонними библиотеками Boost::Test, UnitTest++, но путевого описания не нашел, либо слишком сложно, либо не мой вариант в плане языка или уровня знаний.

Как сделать, что-то похожее на модульное тестирование, но на примере функции в маленьком консольном приложении? Просто подать тестовые наборы с ответом пользователю о прохождении теста, либо его провале? Если добавлять класс, то как реализовать это наиболее "не громоздко"?

Документация на msdn оставляет желать лучшего, создать dll использовать макросс...

Пробовал на примере этой простенькой функции:

```
void sort_mass(int* m, int n)
{

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if ((m[j] % 2) == 0)
            {
                int clon_index = m[j];
                m[j] = m[j + 1];
                m[j + 1] = clon_index;
            }

        }


}
```

Если есть возможность поделиться ссылкой на ресурс, либо реализацию такой идеи на простых примерах буду только рад воспользоваться.

Comment: для с++ пользуюсь [google test](https://github.com/google/googletest). Все просто и удобно

Comment: @tilin, спасибо, начнем знакомиться.